# Как имя константы перевести в string?

Tags: java, android

Есть константа и переменная

```
final int FLAG_GET_TIME = 2;
String str;
```

Как сделать так, чтобы переменная "str" стала равна "FLAG_GET_TIME"?

Comment: Очень странный вопрос. Вы наверняка пытались решить проблему А и сделали вывод что надо сделать Б. Проблема Б у вас не получилась, и вы задаете вопрос с проблемой Б выше. Если вдруг в вашем коде нужно знать конкретное название переменной, то скорее всего вы делаете что-то не так. Задайте вопрос с проблемой А и, наверняка, будет более красивое решение. Ну а если крайне необходимо решить именно это... То @GreyGoblin дал вроде вполне адекватный метод (Сопоставимый с адекватностью самой задачи :) ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используя пакет java.lang.reflect можно получить поля класса и перебрать их в цикле. Например:

```
Field[] fields = MyClass.class.getDeclaredFields();
for (Field field : fields)      
    System.out.println(field.getName());
```

Проблема в том, что возвращаемый getDeclaredFields массив не сортирован и порядок элементов в нем не определен. Так что нельзя рассчитывать, что первое поле в коде будет также первым в массиве.
В вашем условии вы анализируете только статические поля, поэтому можно сделать так:

```
Field[] fields = MyClass.class.getDeclaredFields();
for (Field field : fields)      
   if(Modifier.isStatic(field.getModifiers()))
      str = field.getName();
```

Если статическое поле только одно, то этот код сработает так как вы хотите.